# C# foreach loop not executing

Tags: c#, foreach

I have the following code that only executes the first foreach loop. When I go into the step by step mode in Visual Studio, the program just skips over every subsequent foreach loop. Why is this happening, and is there a workaround? Is there a way to cycle through an IEnumerable<> without using a foreach loop (like a for loop, although I haven't figured out how to do that).

```
using CsvHelper;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;

...

    public class State
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Pop { get; set; }
        public string Ab { get; set; }
        public int Reps { get; set; }
        public double standardQuota { get; set; }
        public int lowerQuota { get; set; }
        public int upperQuota { get; set; }
    }

...

        static void currentRule(int num)
        {
            IEnumerable<State> records = null;
            int size = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a size for the house, greater than the number of states. Current is 435. select 1 for wyoming rule or 2 for cube root.");
            string s = Console.ReadLine();
            size = Int32.Parse(s);
            if (num == 1)
            {
                string path = "C:/.../pop50.csv";
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(path))
                using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                {
                    records = csv.GetRecords<State>();
                    int total = 0;
                    foreach (var state in records)
                    {
                        total += state.Pop;
                    }
                    var standardDivisor = total / size;
                    foreach (var state in records)
                    {
                        state.standardQuota = state.Pop / standardDivisor;
                        state.lowerQuota = (int)Math.Floor(state.standardQuota);
                        state.upperQuota = (int)Math.Ceiling(state.standardQuota);
                        state.Reps = 1;
                        size -= 1;
                    }
                    while (size > 0)
                    {
                        double max = 0;
                        double maxIndex = 0;
                        int i = -1;
                        foreach (var state in records)
                        {
                            i++;
                            var numSeats = state.Reps;
                            var div = state.Pop / Math.Sqrt(size * (size + 1));
                            if (div > max)
                            {
                                max = div;
                                maxIndex = i;
                            }
                        }
                        foreach (var state in records)
                        {
                            if (state.Id == maxIndex)
                            {
                                state.Reps++;
                                size--;
                            }
                        }
                            
                    }
                }
            }
            print(records);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetRecords` returns a stateful `IEnumerable` the yields a single record at the time. The operative word here is stateful - once you've consumed a record (e.g., by iterating over it with a `foreach` loop), it's gone.

There are a few approaches you could take here:

1. Collapse all your in to a single `foreach` loop instead of three different loops which perform different parts of the logic.
2. Call `GetRecords` every time you need to iterate over the records. Note that this will reread the file, so you'll be performing triple the I/O.
3. Convert the iterable to a `List` (e.g., by using Linq's `ToList()`), and then iterate over it whenever you wish. Note that this means you'll be holding the entire file's contents in memory isntead of just a small portion of it.

Answer (score 1):

> *Is there a way to cycle through a IEnumerable<> without using a
> foreach loop (like a for loop, although I haven't figured out how to
> do that).*

Try this to get the enumerator:

---

Option 1 with `Enumerator`:

```
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{        
 var records = csv.GetRecords<State>();
 var enumerator = records.GetEnumerator();
 while(enumerator.MoveNext())
 {
    var currItemEn = enumerator.Current;            
 }
}
```

Option 2 with a `List`:

```
// or if you want a list, save this list and reuse it!
records = csv.GetRecords<State>().ToList<State>();
```

---

**Ref Doc:**
Suggestion, I prefer to get the object list its onetime, easier and better. Based on the ref. from [CsvHelper Page](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/reading/enumerate-class-records/)

Looks like you have **multiple loops** and *resulting in `reuse the Enumerable`*..

> *Convert CSV rows into a class object that is re-used on every
> iteration of the enumerable. Each enumeration will hydrate the given
> record, but only the mapped members. If you supplied a map and didn't
> map one of the members, that member will ---- > not get hydrated with the
> current row's data. ----> Be careful. Any methods that you call on the
> projection that force the evaluation of the IEnumerable, such as
> ToList(), you will **get a list where all the records are the same
> instance** you provided that is hydrated with the last record in the CSV
> file.*

Answer (score 0):

To answer the second part of your question. You can add:

```
using System.Linq;
```

and change this code:

```
foreach(var state in records)
{
   total += state.Pop;
 }
```

To this code:

```
int total = records.Sum(X=> state.Pop);
```

Goodluck!